# PIC18F4550 CPU appear to be not running at external crystal frequency

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator, c, xc8

I am trying to add a 20MHz external crystal oscillator to my PIC18F4550 microcontroller. The external crystal oscillator circuit connections to the PIC18F4450 is as below:
[image]

The Datasheet suggest to use 15pF capacitors for 20MHz crystal however, I have used 22pF by mistake. With that said, when I try to hook up my oscilloscope to check the PIN13 (OSC1) of PIC18 microcontroller, I am able to see the 20MHz sine wave signal present as below. So I decided against replacing the existing 22pF capacitors with 15pF capacitors.

[image]

Then, I used the following code to create a shortest pulse width possible at LATB7.

```
// PIC18F4550 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 5       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HS // Oscillator Selection bits (Internal oscillator, HS oscillator used by USB (INTHS))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = ON         // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF         // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include <pic18f4550.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#define LED LATBbits.LATB7 
#define ON 1
#define OFF 0   

void main(void) {
    TRISBbits.TRISB7 = 0;
    while(1)
     {   
        LED = ON;
        NOP();
        LED = OFF;
     }
     }
```

However, when I monitor the output pin RB7 with oscilloscope, it appears the the pulse width is around 400ns.

[image]

Since the frequency is 20MHz, each cycle would be 50ns. Assuming PIC18F4550 need 4 clock cycles for 1 instruction cycle, shouldn't I be able to achieve a lower pulse width than 400ns? What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**
Assembly listing of the main loop:

```
78:            void main(void) {
79:                TRISBbits.TRISB7 = 0;
7FF0  9E93     BCF TRISB, 7, ACCESS
80:                while(1)
81:                 {   
82:                    LED = ON;
7FF2  8E8A     BSF LATB, 7, ACCESS
83:                    NOP();
7FF4  F000     NOP
84:                    LED = OFF;
7FF6  9E8A     BCF LATB, 7, ACCESS
7FF8  EFF9     GOTO 0x7FF2
7FFA  F03F     NOP
7FFC  EF00     GOTO 0x0
85:                 }
86:                 }
```

**EDIT 2:**
As Tom Carpenter Suggested, I have changed my CONFIG1L and CONFIG1H as follow:

```
// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 5       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL_HS // Oscillator Selection bits (Internal oscillator, HS oscillator used by USB (INTHS))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF
```

As the CPU clock is now 48MHz, each cycle takes 20.83ns. One instruction cycle is 83.33ns. My oscilloscope result match the expectation (Although the output waveform is much distorted at this point - perhaps a separate topic to discuss). Thank you all for your comprehensive answers.

[image]

Comment: Can you get the assembler source of the `main()` loop?  Or disassemble it from the object file?

Comment: @jonathanjo I have added the code as you requested.

Comment: I don't know the specs of the oscilloscope you are using; the overshoot may be real or may just be an artifact of limited scope bandwidth.

Comment: Don't worry about 22pF versus 15pF. As per the datasheet: "Higher capacitance increases the stability of oscillator but also increases the start-up time.". Though also note "These values are not optimized. Different capacitor values may be required to produce acceptable oscillator operation. The user should test the performance of the oscillator over the expected VDD and temperature range for the application.".

Comment: As an aside, you can go faster if you use a different pin with access to the CCP module, in PWM mode. Minimum period is 4 cycles if I'm reading the datasheet correctly - but that's 4 sysclk cycles not 4 instruction cycles (=16 sysclk cycles). (You could also do the same thing with the EUSART port.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the PIC running at 20MHz, and each instruction being 4 crystal clock cycles, this gives an instruction clock rate of 5MHz (or 200ns).

It takes 1 instruction cycle to change the output to high (`LED = ON`). Then a second cycle wasted on no operation (`NOP`). Then we turn the output low again, but we won't count that one for the high period.

That means the pulse should be 2 instruction clocks wide. 2 clock cycles at 5MHz gives 400ns. Exactly what you see.

Then for the low period, we have again 1 instruction cycle to set the output low. This is then followed by a jump at the end of the loop to get back to the start, with the jumps (`GOTO`) in the PIC18F family taking 2 instruction clock cycles.

That means the low period of the output should be 1+2 = 3 instruction clocks wide, giving 600ns. Again, what you see.

This is a total time of 1us, or a 1MHz output frequency.

If you were to remove the `NOP`, you would get a 200us pulse width, and 1.25MHz output frequency. This would be the fastest possible output frequency **for this clock configuration**, as all branch instructions will take at least 2 instruction clock cycles.

---

However, your PIC can actually go faster than this. The PIC18F4550 has an internal PLL, which allows increasing the frequency of the CPU clock.

[image: Clock configuration for PIC18F4550]

The PLL is designed to generate a 96MHz clock from the input source, assuming that your source is a suitable frequency. The PLL requires an input frequency of 4MHz, but has a prescaler which helps with this. Your 20MHz crystal is a suitable source, selecting a prescaler of 5 to get the required 4MHz.

The output of the PLL can be used to drive the CPU, however at a minimum divisor factor of 2, giving a maximum CPU frequency of 48MHz. To enable this, you should change the `CONFIG1H` section of your code to:

```
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL // Oscillator Selection bits - use PLL
```

With the CPU at max frequency, you would then have an instruction clock of 48/4 = 12MHz. This would allow you to decrease the pulse width by a factor of 2.4, to get a 83.33ns minimum pulse width, and maximum output frequency of 3MHz.

Answer (score 6):

This is your code:

```
7FF2  8E8A     BSF LATB, 7, ACCESS
7FF4  F000     NOP
7FF6  9E8A     BCF LATB, 7, ACCESS
7FF8  EFF9     GOTO 0x7FF2
```

From [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/39632e.pdf), we see that each is a single instruction cycle except the `GOTO`, which is 2.

[image]

So you'd expect exactly what you're seeing: 20 MHz clock gives 5 MHz instruction cycles; you have a 5-cycle loop; hence 1 us period.

The fastest you can get is with a long loop like this:

```
LOOP  BSF LATB, 7, ACCESS
      BCF LATB, 7, ACCESS
      BSF LATB, 7, ACCESS
      BCF LATB, 7, ACCESS
      # repeat BCF/BSF many times
      GOTO LOOP
```

That will get you a 400 ns period with a little longer every time round the loop.

You can often see little bumps on the voltages at the instruction boundaries, just like on your scope trace, which is often a good clue about what's happening.

[image]

Comment: Yes, was able to lower the pulse width by using PLL as another answer suggested. Thank you for the help.